# Joomla - Component - Form not posting to itself!

Tags: joomla, components, module

I am learning Joomla and doing examples out of books. Im working on an example that does not throw any errors but doesnt do what I want.

The example is to create a suggestion form that posts the data to itself which is then put into a database. The form  does not return to itself tho! When the submit button is pressed it takes you to http://www.perfectclaims.com/joomla/index.php?suggestion=&email=&location=&Submit=Send+Suggestion

Please ignore the look of the site as im only playing with different things! The site will not look anything like this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `option` variable present in your request. Set it to `com_nameofyourcomponent`. Joomla loads exactly one component for every request and relies on the `option` variable to determine this.